# How to check if variable is a number in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

const(0)
const(X):- number(X).

?- const(0).
true

?- const(1).
false

I'm new to Prolog.
I'm trying to check if X is a number. I don't want to manually enter const(0),cont(1) each time. How should I do this?

Comment: It looks like yo did not *load* the module where you defined `const/1`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are right. However, when I load the module it still gives wrong answer

Comment: You need to define the predicate first? Type `[user]` to go into editing mode, type `const(X):- number(X).` type CTRL-D

Comment: @DavidTonhofer it only gives me true response to the predicate I defined. For example, I defined const(0),  -? const(0). is true. However const(9). is false

Answer (score 0):

integer/1 is what You need .

```
?- integer(0) .
true.

?- integer(9).
true.

?- integer(foo).
false.

?- integer("bar").
false.
```